# How can this array manipulation problem be solved scalably?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with JS and came across an interesting Array manipulation problem. I'm aware that the problem can be solved with a tremendous *if - else if* clause, but am actually looking for a more scalable answer.

I have two arrays (let's call them *input* and *output*) whose contents are related to each other. The first array contains a list of ids, and the second array is actually a response from an API (I have no power over the API) matching the ids of the input array.

---

Examples: If I have an input array of `[1, 2, 3]` I will end up with an output array of

```
[
  { id: 1, data: "Some data for id 1" },
  { id: 2, data: "Some data for id 2" },
  { id: 3, data: "Some data for id 3" }
]
```

So far so good. However, the problem arises if I have an input array like `[1, 2, 2]`, which is possible and intentional. In this situation I end with an output array of

```
[
  { id: 1, data: "Some data for id 1" },
  { id: 2, data: "Some data for id 2" }
]
```

In the above case I would need to have the output array be of `length === 3` and the third item to be a copy of the second item like so

```
[
  { id: 1, data: "Some data for id 1" },
  { id: 2, data: "Some data for id 2" },
  { id: 2, data: "Some data for id 2" }
]
```

Two more examples for clarity:
Input: `[4, 4, 4]`, what I get:

```
[
  { id: 4, data: "Some data for id 4" }
]
```

What I need to achieve:

```
[
  { id: 4, data: "Some data for id 4" },
  { id: 4, data: "Some data for id 4" },
  { id: 4, data: "Some data for id 4" }
]
```

Last one, input: `[3, 3, 7]`
What I get:

```
[
  { id: 3, data: "Some data for id 3" },
  { id: 7, data: "Some data for id 7" }
]
```

What I need to achieve:

```
[
  { id: 3, data: "Some data for id 3" },
  { id: 3, data: "Some data for id 3" },
  { id: 7, data: "Some data for id 7" },
]
```

---

I am working with a maximum array length of three, so an *if-else* clause comparing lengths and values is sufficient for this, but is there a dynamic and scalable way to manipulate the output array in the intended way? I was not able to think if anything from my mind.

EDIT: I should add that the *data* part can be anything, not just the text I am giving here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const output = input.map(id => transformToOutput(id))`

Comment: I don't understand why you think this problem is hard to scale or should require complicated logic. Am I missing something important?

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm not really sure either. Seems like there is *more work* involved to shrink the output array. Producing a 1:1 result seems the easiest thing - even a loop would naturally do the same `for (let id of input) output.push(transformToOutput(id)`. In order to eliminate duplicates, there needs to be more code and thus a more complex solution.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more clear. Essentially the data part can be anything, as it is a data response from an API. That is why one cannot just construct the output array from the input array in a straightforward approach.

Comment: I don't see how this changes things. The simplest approach is to get 1 result for each 1 item in the input array. Anything that causes a discrepancy in the number of inputs and outputs would be more complex even by a little.

Comment: @AarniJoensuu give examples of "anything" data and its outputs.

Comment: Example input `[1, 2, 3]`, example output from API: `[ { id: 1, data: "a string" }, { id: 2, data: [1,2,3,4,5] }, { id: 3, data: [5,4,3,2,1] } ]`

Comment: from what I understand, you need to create a function that returns random values and use it to set the "data" variable, within the logic of the "map" function.

Answer (score 1):

The **map** function allows us to create new arrays from a pre-existing one.

```js
const outputArray = inputArray.map(id => {
    return {
        id: id,
        data: "Some data for id " + id
    }
});
```